# Running a python script remotely with local files

Tags: python

I can run the script with arguments remotely with the following command:

```
ssh user@machine python < script.py - arg1 arg2
```

However, the `script.py` must load a local file `mysql_str.json` which comprises `mysql` connect strings. So I have 2 questions:

1. How to pass the `mysql_str.json` as well?
2. Assume my computer and the target machine are connected via public network, how to ensure the security during passing the `mysql_str.json`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'd need to `scp` the local file, since you're running your file from within the remote machine.

Comment: @AdamGold Thanks for your reply. This works but is there any other solution since I may have dozens of machines...